WooCommerce - Programmatically trigger the "Save changes" button for the variations
In an e-shop I noticed in the Related products section that for some products I'm getting the "Select options" label, while for some others I'm getting the "Read more" label that redirects to the single product page of that product.
According to WC source code that's determined in class-wc-product-variable.php with the code:
public function add_to_cart_text() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', $this->is_purchasable() ? __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' ), $this );
}

So the problem in this case is that for no obvious reason, some products are seemingly not purchasable. So I did this: I visited the edit page of one of them, went to the Variations tab, opened a random variation, changed a value (ie. I typed a character in the variation's SKU field) then reverted it (I deleted the character), just to enable the Save changes button at the bottom. I clicked the Save changes button, so the variations were refreshed.
And voila, the product got purchasable and the label "Select options" was available for it in the Related products section...
So, my question is this: How can I programmatically simulate this for some thousands of variable products? I noticed that when the Save changes button is pressed, and AJAX request runs in the background for the action woocommerce_save_variations but the problem is that it also has a lot of data POSTed for the variations.
So even if I get the action to trigger, how am I going to assemble all the data posted?
I know my questions is more a conceptual type, but I'm not sure what's the correct route to follow mostly.

I'd maybe try and figure out first, if this really needs a coding solution - or if perhaps a database update can solve the issue. See if comparing the database contents for one specific product before and after you saved the variation, shows some easily spotable difference that might be relevant ...?

I've thought about comparing the before/after DB snapshot of the relevant table (postmeta, that is, right?), but decided to ask here first, as it seemed impossible to not have a solution programmatically... Plus I doubt no one has ever faced it in the past!
